# How to get all the orders in shopify with fulfillment status as shipped using REST API in python?

Tags: python, rest, shopify

I am trying to get all the orders on a shopify store which have the fulfillment status as shipped.

When I use the following in the web browser url, I am able to get the desired results:

```
https://<store_name>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/orders/search.json?query=fulfillment_status:shipped
```

However, when I try to use the following piece of python (Python 3.8.2) code, the json returned is empty. What am I missing?

```
>>> payload = {'fulfillment_status':'shipped', 'limit':100}
>>> response = requests.get( "https://%s.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/orders.json" % (SHOP_NAME), auth=(API_KEY,PASSWORD), params=payload)
>>> response
<Response [200]>
>>> response.json()
{'orders': []}
```

Comment: Its going to hard to debug this because we can't recreate your situation. Suggestions: instead of using string interpolation and params, requests.get the same string that works in the browser. See if just that works. Print all fields of the response and see how that looks. Anything suspicious? Try to reproduce this http call with curl or httpie. Do they work?

Answer (score 0):

Try by using the following URL:

```
url = "https://{apikey}:{password}@{hostname}/admin/api/{version}/{resource}.json?limit=250&fulfillment_status=shipped"
response = requests.request("GET", url)
```

There is a tutorial on how you can get all orders from Shopify, you may find it useful:

https://predictivehacks.com/how-to-get-all-orders-from-shopify-in-python/